# UIScrollView in UITableViewCell not scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am adding a cell to a UITableView which has a scrollview, the code I have in the cell is :

```
UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 320, 44)];
UIView *labelView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(4, 4, 80 * _labels.count, 44)];
for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < _labels.count; i++) {
    NSString *aLabel = [_labels objectAtIndex:i];
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(i * 70, 3, 60, 30)];
    button.tag = i;
    [button setTitle:aLabel forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];
    [labelView addSubview:button];
}
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(labelView.frame.size.width, labelView.frame.size.height);
[scrollView addSubview:labelView];
[self addSubview:scrollView];
```

However this does not scroll :(. If I have the same code segment outside the tableview and add this directly to the view, it works as expected. What am I missing?

Comment: have you tried [self.contentView addSubview: scrollView];

Answer (score 0):

Try [cell addSubview:scrollView];

Comment: The code above is in a custom TableViewCell.m class, so [self addSubview:scrollView] is actually adding to the UITableViewCell instance

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the scrollView to the contentView of the UITableViewCell and maybe setting

```
self.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = NO
```

From the UITableViewCell reference [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/contentView)

*Discussion
The content view of a UITableViewCell object is the default superview for content displayed by the cell. If you want to customize cells by simply adding additional views, you should add them to the content view so they will be positioned appropriately as the cell transitions into and out of editing mode.*