# setContentOffset not working for UIScrollView inside UITableViewCell for the first time

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have a horizontal **UIScrollView** which is added as a subview inside custom **UITableViewCell**. For some cases, I want to change the scrollview content offset which I achieve by doing this code

```
cell.horizontalScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 300, y: cell.horizontalScrollView.contentOffset.y), animated: true)
```

inside the `UITableView`'s `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function and `tableview.reloadData()` is called whenever I needed to scroll it programmatically.

The issue is, this does not work for the first time. ie,

When the tableview is loaded for the first time, the scrollviews inside the visible cells **does not get scrolled** according to the code. Its offset is just at (0,0). ***----*** (**This is the issue!**)

But after that, when I scrolled the `tableView`, then the new cells(reused cells) gets updated and scrollviews position gets changed. ***(which I needed from the start itself!)***

So, I want to change the `UIScrollView`'s **initial offset**(position) programmatically. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atlast, I found the solution after sitting for a couple of days!

Had to implement `layoutIfNeeded` for the `UITableViewCell` inside the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method before setting the `contentOffset` for the `UIScrollView`.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomCell
    cell.layoutIfNeeded()
    cell.horizontalScrollView.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 300, y: cell.horizontalScrollView.contentOffset.y), animated: false)
    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement this is to subclass your cell and then set the content offset in `layoutSubviews` method.

Comment: Great! Now it works initially, but when I need to change again programmatically, it does not scroll at all! It just being static at the initial position. @tedd

Comment: Which is not scrolling the tableview or the uiscrollview? Is your scrollview created manually?

Comment: The scrollview inside the cells not gets scrolled, I used setContentoffset for it again to change the position,
scrollview is added inside cell in storyboard and connected to viewcontroller

Comment: try adding this code inside `layoutSubviews` in your subclass `self.contentView.userInteractionEnabled = NO`

reference: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936444/uiscrollview-in-uitableviewcell-not-scrolling)

Comment: this code will disable the user interaction of all the subviews inside the cell right? that should not happen, i have another pan and tap gestures inside it. and also, it doesnot work at all. i can't understand the logic behind it :(

Comment: for more detailed explanation please look at michelalbers' answer [refence](https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController/issues/498) or you can do more researching about the issue